Timeout error on react-export-excel library
I'm having a problem installing the react-export-excel. For some reason the connection to git keeps getting a timeout message, and I don't know why.
It's an old code that suddenly stopped working with some dependencies and this one seems to be the most problematic of them.
Any advises on how to deal with this or any other library I could use instead of this one (that might not need that many changes to the code since it is used throughout a big part of my code).
> npm i react-export-excel
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! A git connection error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/securedeveloper/js-xlsx.git
npm ERR! ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\00435764\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-22T19_13_42_855Z-debug-0.log


check the log file, maybe there is more information.
